# How to limit number after Decimal in jQuery Spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-spinner

I am using **jQuery Spinner** like this

```
 $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
      step: 0.1,
      numberFormat: "n"
    });
```

And it shows always numbers like **0.01** but I need to show it like **0.1**.

By API it seems like is impossible to do http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#option-numberFormat

Any clue?

Comment: Can't reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/puhtkoqq/, are you using anything else?

Comment: Ya, provide minimalistic code to replicate your issue. Cannot reproduce this behaviour too   http://jsfiddle.net/o7dLu2cz/

Comment: @Spokey Well... I use this code only. And I use globalization code as well like it has this demo http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#decimal

Comment: Do you set an initial value for your input?

Comment: @Spokey Yes it is 0. When I spin then it changes to 0.10.

Comment: Remove `numberFormat`, it changes it do a decimal

Answer (score 0):

Well...

Thanks all guys for their comments

Here is the answer

[Set decimal format in jQuery Globalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996151/set-decimal-format-in-jquery-globalize)

```
$( "#spinner" ).spinner({
      step: 0.1,
      numberFormat: "n1"
    });
```